# Vertical align floats on decimal dot

Tags: lisp, floating-point, format, common-lisp, vertical-alignment

Is there a simple way to align on the decimal dot a column of floats? In other words, I would like an output like the one of (vertical bars '|' are there only for clarity purpose)

```
(format t "~{|~16,5f|~%~}" '(798573.467 434.543543 2.435 34443.5))
```

which is

```
|    798573.44000|
|       434.54355|
|         2.43500|
|     34443.50000|
```

but with trailing spaces instead of zeros, as follows:

```
|    798573.44   |
|       434.54355|
|         2.435  |
|     34443.5    |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think that this can easily be done with `format`'s inbuilt control characters, but you could pass your own function to it:

```
(defun my-f (stream arg colon at &rest args)
  (declare (ignore colon at))
  (destructuring-bind (width digits &optional (pad #\Space)) args
    (let* ((string (format nil "~v,vf" width digits arg))
           (non-zero (position #\0 string :test #'char/= :from-end t))
           (dot (position #\. string :test #'char= :from-end t))
           (zeroes (- (length string) non-zero (if (= non-zero dot) 2 1)))
           (string (nsubstitute pad #\0 string :from-end t :count zeroes)))
      (write-string string stream))))
```

You can use it like this:

```
CL-USER> (format t "~{|~16,5/my-f/|~%~}" '(798573.467 434.543543 2.435 34443.5 10))
|    798573.44   |
|       434.54355|
|         2.435  |
|     34443.5    |
|        10.0    |
NIL
```

The padding character defaults to `#\Space`, and may be given as a third argument like this: `"~16,5,' /my-f/"`.

An alternative implementation using `loop`:

```
(defun my-f (stream arg colon at &rest args)
  (declare (ignore colon at))
  (loop with string = (format nil "~v,vf" (car args) (cadr args) arg)
        and seen-non-zero = nil
        for i from (1- (length string)) downto 0
        as char = (char string i)
        if (char/= char #\0) do (setq seen-non-zero t)
        collect (if (and (not seen-non-zero)
                         (char= char #\0)
                         (not (char= #\. (char string (1- i)))))
                    (or (caddr args) #\Space)
                    char) into chars
        finally (write-string (nreverse (coerce chars 'string)) stream)))
```

(Disclaimer: Maybe I overlooked something easier in the documentation of `format`.)

Comment: I think "elegance" wins out under the guise that this can be done at all within the 'format' framework by simply adding a function rather than having to toss out the entire kit.

Comment: Will, I meant my implementation of `my-f`, which could maybe be done better. For example, it probably shouldn't drop the `0` from `1.0`. Sure, it's nice that `format` is so flexible!

Comment: Somthing's strange, why 798573.467 displays as 798573.44 ? (this happens in plain format too) @danlei

Comment: Danlei, it seems that your 1st excellent solution may well handle the `1.0` cases with a slight 2 lines fix (I report only the relevant lines): `... (dot-pos (position #\. string :test #'char= :from-end t)) (zeroes (- (length string) position 1 (if (eql position dot-pos) 1 0))) ...`. You might want to edit your original post to make it simpler. @danlei

Comment: mmj, sure, I'll update the answer. Thanks for the suggestion! (I'll leave the second implementation as an alternative.)

Comment: mmj, Use double floats or long floats for higher precision: `(format t "~{|~,5,/my-f/|~%~}" '(798573.467d0))`.