# LibGDX: Align text on decimal dot

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I align text in a way that I can always have the dot in the middle independently of the digit number or the string size?

I am creating my first HUD, and I need to have my numbers aligned like the following example:

> __12 . 01  << Take those "_" as blank spaces
>
> _123 . 123
>
> 2000 . 0615
>
> 3142 . 1

Something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358355/vertical-align-floats-on-decimal-dot) but for java and libGDX.

For now, I generate my text using the `font.draw()`method, but it looks too limited...

```
BitmapFont font = new... // the font is generated through a .ttf
// Draw text
String pointsText = String.format("%.6f", 10.01f);
GlyphLayout layout = new GlyphLayout();
layout.setText(TextureManager.font, pointsText);
font.draw(batch, layout, 0, 0);
```

If I draw this, I can positionate the string anywhere I want in the window, but I can't align it like I want, because this is just a rectangle.

Currently I'm reading about `Scene2D`, and it looks like I can easily manage my HUD elements with this library, but even with it, I don't think that using a `Label` object can solve my problem in some way (or maybe I am trying to solve this in the wrong way).

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The `String pointsText = String.format("%.6f", myNumber);` was a provisional solution, by this way I get numbers like:

> __12 . 010000
>
> _123 . 123000
>
> 2000 . 061500
>
> 3142 . 100000

And in fact they are "aligned" but this is not what I was looking for.

Comment: just to clarify a little bit... do you know all the numbers before listing them or are they added dynamically one by one?

Comment: I calculate the number, so I guess they are added dynamically... the `10.01f` was just an example, in reality, this number is based on the player score and I use a formula to get them...

Comment: I think that your solution to pad numbers with trailing zeros and align them to the right its ok. That is what I would do. Having all the zeros after the dot make them more readable for me.